# What is a good antonym for "commiserate"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The [Cambridge Dictionary defines Commiserate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/commiserate):

> to feel or express sympathy for someone’s suffering or unhappiness

In my experience/opinion, it's more than sympathy and implies a joint suffering and is often used ironically.  For instance, a sports fanatic might commiserate a team's loss with a fellow fan.

Using a similar sports example, what might I do with a fellow fan if our team wins?

Comment: [*Gloat*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gloat), perhaps?

Comment: What has your research turned up? What hasn't worked? What has come close?

Comment: Maybe "gloat", but I feel like it implies direction, bragging.

Comment: *Celebrate*, though it's possible to do that by one's lonesome, as well.

Comment: One antonym of sympathy is *indifference*. So, "show indifference to someone's suffering."

Comment: Do you mean antonym of "express", antonym of "sympathy" or antonym of "suffering or unhappiness"?

Comment: You need to define "opposite".  Does it mean that there's nothing to commiserate about, or that the individuals do not interact in commiseration?

Comment: I realize from a couple of the responses that is the case.  I will see if I can add some verbiage, but "Celebrate" is exemplary of what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have just updated the post.

Comment: There may be an issue because *commiserate* doesn't take a direct object. A sports fanatic might commiserate **with** a fellow fan **over** a loss. Consequently your "antonym" may differ as well: the range of answers certainly suggests some confusion. I've added the [single-word-request] tag: please review its [tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) especially the checklist and see if the question might be narrowed a bit.

Comment: Wallow in your victory.

Comment: @aparente001 That's exactly the sentiment I had in mind!  Too bad there seems to be no single word for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you liked *wallow in your victory* so much, but prefer a single word, I will propose

[***revel***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/revel)

> verb: 1. To take great pleasure or delight: She reveled in her unaccustomed leisure.
>
> 2. To engage in uproarious festivities; make merry.

Related:

> noun: (often *revels*) A boisterous festivity or celebration; merrymaking.

*(thefreedictionary.com)*

I think this is the word you are looking for, because I have heard news reports that after a particular game, some revelers have gotten out of hand.  This has given me the impression that *reveling* after an intense sports match can be an intense group experience.

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: Commiserate a loss and revel in victory!

Answer (score 16):

If two fans aren't commiserating, they must be [**celebrating**](http://dictionary.com/browse/celebrate)

> to commemorate (an event) with ceremonies or festivities:
>   *to celebrate the success of a new play.*

This is definitely appropriate, as this snippet from an Independent article on the Chicago Cubs winning the World Series:

> Chicago's landmark victory in the World Series has triggered a wave of emotional and touching videos of elderly fans celebrating back at home

Comment: Perfect in context!

Comment: Yep, perfect in context! Just the word I could immediately think of after reading this question.

Comment: This is very good, and a correct answer, but I think "revel" really has the feel I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

#### Congratulate

*Congratulations* tend to pass from the loser (or their fans) to the winner (or then fans) and so are a direct opposite of *commiserations*, which are from a winner to a loser.

> to express pleasure to (a person), as on a happy occasion:
> *They congratulated him on his win.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/congratulate))

This is often seen at the end of a game show in the form of:

> Commiserations to [losing team], but congratulations to tonight's winners [winning team]!

This also fits if you want to fit this into your situation of two winning fans:

> They congratulated each other on another win for their team.

> Russian fans congratulate each other in the street after the finish of the Russia-Czech republic soccer match at Euro 2012, in Moscow

([Alamy Photograph Title](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-russian-fans-congratulate-each-other-in-the-street-after-the-finish-100059611.html))

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, especially in the context of others' suffering, is to [be/stand **aloof**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aloof):

> distant, unsympathetic, or supercilious in manner, attitude, or feeling

Comment: Using the sports example, I would not go "stand aloof" with a fellow Piggers fan if we won the pork-bowl.  I mean, I might, but it's not what I'm going for here.  I think Celebrate is definitely the closest to what I'm hoping to find.

Answer (score 1):

#### Rejoice

*Rejoice*, which means: "to feel joy or great delight," is another celebratory word with less potentially negative connotation than *revel*.

Examples of *rejoice* in a sentence:

> We all rejoiced over our friend's good luck.
> We rejoiced over our unexpected victory on the soccer field.

(See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rejoice))

Answer (score 0):

Galvanize -

As an opposite to commiserate, I think that perhaps this word would work depending on the context.

For example, "The community chose not to commiserate when a fire burned down their historical center; rather, they galvanized and began to remodel the entire downtown district."